# With Helidon Metrics how do I mimic the OEM metrics?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, microprofile, helidon, thanos

With the metrics available in Helidon, how do I make graphs in Grafana to mimic what we used to have in OEM?

For example:

[image: OEM Screenshot]

We seem to have Microprofile metrics, such as "base_gc_time_seconds" but I guess we need to use rate or something?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If what you need is "per minute", you can use query like `increase(base_gc_time_seconds[1m])` and set min time interval in query options to 1m.

Comment: Also, I've heard that there is a OEM plugin for Grafana, maybe it has what you need out of the box. But had no luck integrating it personally, so no guarantees.